# C# Set Focus To 3rd Party Controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a 3rd party drop down treeview in my asp.net C# code

```
<ct:ASDropDownTreeView ID="astvMyTree" runat="server"... />
```

I'd like to set focus on it in the code behind. Obviously the C# control.Focus() only works on Windows controls.
I've tried javascript

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "control_focus", "ASDropDownTreeView.focus();", true);
```

but it doesn't work either. Is there a way I'm supposed to declare the 3rd party controls in javascript or does it also only work on html and windows controls?

Comment: You need to find out the actual client name of the treeview control inside the ASDropDownTreeView. One way is to view the page source, track that name and use it inside your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the control name on the client side somehow. ASP.NET controls have         ClientID property that tell you what will be control name on client side. If your controls have something similar then you can use this.

Other option is to run the page, view html source and see client name.

Comment: Thanks. I've made some progress with this